# How to create a polling in a node.js express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, recursion, pooling

I want to create a **polling system** on my node.js server.

I want him to **send a request at regular intervals**.

As long as the answer is positive the call interval does not change.

If the answer is no, I want to reduce or lengthen this interval. There is a problem of **memory used to deal with too (recursion).**

**What advice can you give me for creating this system?** I can't find any resources that deal with an identical problem. Do you know of an **npm package** that can do this? or do you advise me to build it into an **object**?
Thx !

Comment: Do you mean polling?

Comment: Why recursion? You can use setInterval()